# Separate APIM Stores in internal and DMZ network

Tags: wso2-api-manager

We'd like to create separate APIM stores in our internal network and DMZ. I've been going through the documentation, and I've seen you can publish to multiple store (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Publish+to+Multiple+External+API+Stores) but this is not exactly what I'm looking for, since you need to visit the "main" store to subscribe to an API.
I'd like to have the option from a single publisher instance to check of to which stores an API must be published. Much like the way you can decide to which API gateways you publish your APIs.

Any thoughts or help on this would be great.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once API is published  in publisher api artifacts are stored in registry which is shared between store and publisher. API store get artifacts from this registry and display it. So

1. When create apis use tags to differentiate artifacts e.g tag DMZ, Internal
2. Modify the store to get artifacts based on tags and display